# Use USB OTG mic audio device for audio input ONLY (use mic with headphones)

Tags: audio, usb-on-the-go, android-10, audio-recording, samsung-galaxy-a20

I want to record some audio using a USB mic and my OTG-supporting Android phone. The problem is, because the phone recognizes the mic as an audio input/output device even though the mic has no physical way to make sound, I can’t use the headphone jack while the mic is plugged in. Is there an app or a setting I can use to only use the input portion of the USB audio device, and instead use the 3.5mm headphone jack for output?

Comment: Can you please exactly name the USB microphone you use? May be the mic uses an audio chip that supports input and output (but does no make use of the output) which is then detected by Android.

Comment: It’s a Fifine K669.